# MYSQL - Trigger -update /deletion

Tags: mysql

I have to create a trigger a which captures old and new value while updation & deletion taken place

Audit table :

```
create table if not EXISTS tbl_audits
(
TA_Auditid int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY key,
TA_Name varchar(100),
TA_Oldvalue varchar(1000),
TA_Newvalue varchar(1000),
TA_Actiontaken varchar(100),
TA_createddt datetime,
TA_createdby varchar(100)
)

DELIMITER //


create TRIGGER TRfiledetails_update
BEFORE update on tbl_file_details
for EACH ROW
BEGIN


insert into tbl_audits

set TA_createddt =CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

TA_Actiontaken ='update',

TA_Name ='File',

TA_Oldvalue =old.FL_dtstartdt ,

TA_Newvalue  =new.FL_dtstartdt 


end //

DELIMITER ;
```

In my main table i have to create trigger an event  on two columns `startdt` and `enddate`.

In this case I  would like to know whether I need  to create two triggers separately for each column.

Is it possible to create two columns action on same trigger or need to create separate columns in audit table.

Comment: To begin with, edit your question please (four space for code text) so it will be easier to read it ! I'm new with TRIGGER, but it's mostly a script that will be RUN when an EVENT happen (before insert, after update, etc.). So if you want to create two columns on same EVENT, you can do it in one trigger I think, if you need two different EVENT you need two TRIGGER. Don't know if I understand well your question, is it what you'd like to know?

Comment: My doubt is how to capture two column values in one trigger since I am having only two fields to capture old value and new value.I am not having separate two columns to capture old start date,old end date values .Both old values should be captured in one column.I think you got my point

Comment: I am sorry I don't really understand your problem...What doesn't work with your current trigger and what do you expect as result? Right now it looks like BEFORE you UPDATE your table "tbl_file_details" you put the OLD value of "FL_dtstartdt" in the table "tbl_audits" in the field "TA_Oldvalue" and the NEW value of "FL_dtstartdt" in "TA_NEWvalue", this is not what you want?

Comment: Your right Mickael..! This trigger works only when start date changes takes place.If end date and start date update takes place at the same time how to capture in audit table in same trigger?

Comment: Oh ok I understand ! Well the easiest way I see now is to change your table "tbl_audits" with TA_Oldstartvalue, TA_Newstartvalue, TA_Oldendvalue and TA_Newendvalue, with some default value (NULL, "", false...as you wish !) then you TRIGGER should test if you have startdt, enddate or both then UPDATE what you need ! I don't think you can have all information in only 2 columns (or with a VARCHAR type field and some CONCAT between your data to have something like OLDValue = "startdt : date - enddate : date",...this doesn't look very good !

Comment: Thanks @MickaelLeger ..!